# Relative vs fullpath when executing file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When executing cmd/batch/exe file from the powershell command line (or within .ps1 script file), I see the following behavior:

1. Using relative path:

   `./bin/<file to execute> -> executes in same shell windows`
2. Using full path:

   `d:/fullpath/bin/<file to execute> -> executes in new shell (window)`

Can anybody shed some light on this behavior and how to influence this (with other words let the fullpath execute in same shell window)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (tried a .bat file). It is executed in the same window in both cases.

Comment: I also don't have this behaviour.  What happens if you put `& ` in front of the line?  Same result?  And just wondering: what if you use backslashes?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior.  Can you provide more information?